# PHP: Showing currency sign if input is a number

Tags: php

I have a field that lets me enter a price for a product in 'edit post'.

Here's how it's currently called:

```
<span class="price"> "$" <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'si-price',true); ?> </span>
```

Because some products are discontinued, I would like to only show the "$" if what I type in the box is a number. That way I can have products with no price, and have some products marked as "coming soon" etc. without having the '$' in front of it.

I have tried:

```
<?php  
    $price = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'si-price',true);
        foreach ($price as $element) { 
            if (is_numeric($element)) { 
                echo '$' $price; 
                } else { 
                echo $price;
                } 
        } 
?>
```

No joy! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

According to documentation of [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) , It will return a single value if the third parameter is true. It should be false to return an array.

```
<?php  
$price = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'si-price');
    foreach ($price as $element) { 
        if (is_numeric($element)) { 
            echo '$' . $element; 
            } else { 
            echo $element;
            } 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: That did something. But the site is outputting "$Array"

Comment: sorry I didn't correct your old code. Let me edit that.

Comment: Think I got it:

Changed $price to get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'si-price',true) in the Echo.

Comment: It was exactly what I needed to get past the issue! Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are just missing a "." to concatenate the string and variable. It should read:

```
    echo '$' . $price;
```

Comment: Also for the future, this is a purely PHP question. Ask or check it in "Stack Overflow", not Wordpress.

Comment: That took care of the error, but the price is still not displaying for some reason. I'll head over to stack overflow :)